# How to write fixture files for testing models

Tags: python, django, database, testing, fixtures

I want to test my database and Django app via fixtures and Testcases. The problem is that I cannot find any information on how to create fixtures, especially regarding relationships.

I tried in the Python CLI to create objects and relate them to each other, but it won't execute the dumpdata method afterwards.

Can you give me instructions on how to do that, focusing on database models and relationships (1-1,1-n,n-m)?

---

Here are my models. When I try to execute dumpdata via the Python console with the manage.py I get a syntax error. Maybe I don't understand the dumpdata method enough.

```
from operator import mod
from pyexpat import model
from django.db import models

class Chatroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Connection(models.Model):
    connectionID = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=48)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    websocketURL = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    isOnline = models.BooleanField()

class User(models.Model):
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=15,primary_key=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    chatrooms = models.ManyToManyField(Chatroom)
    connection = models.OneToOneField(Connection, 
    on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class Message(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    chatroom = models.ForeignKey(Chatroom,on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class Picture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

Comment: Can you add your model(s) and example data that you want to create a fixture for? What exactly do you mean by ` won't execute the dumpdata method`, if you got an error can you add it to your question too?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.